# Как перекинуть переменные в html файл?

Tags: python, telebot

пишу телеграмм бота, который принимает некоторые переменные и создаёт словарь. Хочу перекинуть эти переменные в html файл

У меня есть переменные, которые создаются пользователем, которые он вводит в боте. Эти переменные сохраняются в словаре. Но вот теперь мне нужно перекинуть или применить эти переменные в pdf файл и html файл. Но при этом в этих pdf и html файлах уже есть шаблонный текст, который изменять нельзя, а нужно изменить только конкретные слова из текста на полученные переменные. И потом уже отправить изменённый файл. Отправлять умею, но не изменённые.
Мб надо .format() использовать, но я пока-что не особо понял как с ним работать в этой ситуации.

```
import telebot

@bot.message_handler(commands=['cv'])
def echo_all(message):
    name = 'pisapopa'
    html = f'''{name} '''
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Загрузка файла')
    with open('sh.html', 'r') as file:
        rock = file.read().replace('{name}', html)
        file_v1 = open('sh.html', 'a')
        file_v1.write(rock]
        print(rock)
 
        bot.send_document(message.chat.id, rock)

bot.infinity_polling()
```

html

```
Civil {name}, год {year}, место {place}
```

Comment: Для HTML файла (или любого другого текстового формата, не pdf) удобнее всего воспользоваться готовым шаблонизатором, который умеет подставлять значения перемннных/словарей в разметку. Один из самых популярных в python-мире это [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую изучить